# Add a new Constructor to Custom View android

Tags: android, generics, constructor, custom-view

I want to add new constructor to my custom view to get parameter. This is my case:

Variable in another class:

```
A<T> customView;
```

"A" custom view class example:

```
public class A<T extends B> extends ViewGroup {

     private Class<T> requestClass;
}
```

How can i get requestClass at initialization time of my view  ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static method instead a constructor.

```
public class A<T extends B> extends ViewGroup {

     private Class<T> requestClass;

     public static <T extends B> A<T> newInstance(Class<T> requestClass) {
         A<T> instance = new A<>();
         instance.requestClass = requestClass;
         return instance;
     }

     public A(){}
}
```

In your another class:

```
A<BImpl> customView = A.newInstance(BImpl.class);
```

Comment: this is a possible solution. however, i am using this view in xml so i am getting it using findViewById.

Comment: Make `A` extends `Fragment` and add to your layout using `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add` instead of getting it using `findViewById`.

Comment: you can not have default no argument constructor in ViewGroup class